# Add custom icons to font awesome

Tags: svg, webfonts, font-awesome

I love the [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/) icon font and want to use it for most of the icons on my site but there are a few custom svg icons that I'd need in addition to what's offered.

I noticed that the [.svg version of Font Awesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Customize-Font-Awesome) is composed mostly of these `<glyph />` elements:

```
...
<glyph unicode="&#xf0b2;" horiz-adv-x="1536" d="M0 80v477q0 51 24.5 61.5t59.5 -24.5l162 -162l340 338l-338 338l-164 -164q-35 -35 -59.5 -25.5t-24.5 60.5v477q0 31 23 57q27 23 57 23h477q51 0 61.5 -24.5t-24.5 -59.5l-160 -158l338 -338l332 334l-162 162q-35 35 -24.5 59.5t61.5 24.5h477q33 0 55 -23 q25 -25 25 -57v-477q0 -51 -24.5 -61.5t-59.5 24.5l-162 162l-334 -334l338 -336l158 160q35 35 59.5 24.5t24.5 -61.5v-477q0 -35 -25 -55q-23 -25 -55 -25h-477q-51 0 -61.5 24.5t24.5 59.5l166 166l-336 336l-340 -340l162 -162q35 -35 24.5 -59.5t-61.5 -24.5h-477 q-31 0 -55 25q-25 20 -25 55z" />
<glyph unicode="&#xf0c0;" horiz-adv-x="1880" d="M0 852v152q0 18 1 47.5t10 56.5t29.5 46.5t57.5 19.5q-45 29 -71.5 75.5t-26.5 104.5q0 43 16.5 82t46 68.5t68.5 46t82 16.5q45 0 84 -16.5t67.5 -46t46 -68.5t17.5 -82q0 -57 -27.5 -104t-72.5 -76q37 0 57.5 -19.5t29.5 -46.5t11 -56.5t2 -47.5v-152 q-14 -8 -23.5 -18.5t-27.5 -10.5h-328q-16 0 -26.5 10.5t-22.5 18.5zM158 57v387q0 78 45 138.5t98 109.5q10 10 25.5 21.5t33.5 15.5q18 6 41 7t45 5q61 10 130 19.5t135 19.5q-90 57 -144.5 151.5t-54.5 207.5q0 88 34 166.5t92 136t136 91.5t166 34t166 -34t136 -91.5 t92 -136t34 -166.5q0 -113 -54 -207t-145 -152q66 -10 134.5 -19t130.5 -20q23 -4 45 -5t41 -7q18 -4 33.5 -15.5t27.5 -21.5q66 -59 103.5 -116.5t37.5 -131.5v-387q-12 -6 -20 -13t-18.5 -14t-23.5 -14.5t-36 -15.5h-1368q-35 0 -54.5 22.5t-43.5 34.5zM1452 852v152 q0 18 2 47.5t11.5 56.5t30 46.5t56.5 19.5q-45 29 -72.5 75.5t-27.5 104.5q0 43 16.5 82t46 68.5t68.5 46t84 16.5q43 0 82 -16.5t68.5 -46t46 -68.5t16.5 -82q0 -57 -26.5 -104t-71.5 -76q37 0 56.5 -19.5t28.5 -46.5t11 -56.5t2 -47.5v-152q-12 -8 -22.5 -18.5 t-26.5 -10.5h-328q-18 0 -27.5 10.5t-23.5 18.5z" />
<glyph unicode="&#xf0c1;" horiz-adv-x="1597" d="M0 1137q0 88 34 166.5t92 137t136 92.5t168 34q86 0 166 -33t139 -92q8 -8 21.5 -20.5t26 -25t21.5 -25.5t9 -25q0 -18 -12 -31q-6 -8 -25 -12q-47 -10 -88 -22.5t-86 -31.5q-4 -4 -16 -4t-25.5 10.5t-31 21.5t-42 21.5t-57.5 10.5q-35 0 -66.5 -13.5t-54 -37t-36 -54 t-13.5 -67.5q0 -41 17.5 -75t43 -63.5t56.5 -56.5t57 -53l180 -178q23 -25 54.5 -37t66.5 -12q43 0 73 16t46 16q12 0 39 -21.5t55.5 -49t50 -55t21.5 -42.5q0 -29 -36 -51t-83 -38.5t-94 -26t-72 -9.5q-86 0 -164.5 33t-140.5 92l-303 305q-61 59 -94 139.5t-33 166.5z M578 1010q0 29 35.5 51t82.5 38.5t94 26t72 9.5q86 0 166 -33t139 -92l303 -305q61 -59 94 -139.5t33 -166.5q0 -90 -33.5 -167.5t-92 -136t-137.5 -92.5t-167 -34q-86 0 -165.5 34t-139.5 93q-8 8 -21.5 19.5t-25.5 25t-21.5 26.5t-9.5 26q0 18 13 28q6 8 24 12 q47 10 88 22.5t86 33.5q12 4 17 4q12 0 25.5 -10.5t30.5 -21.5t41 -21.5t58 -10.5q72 0 121 49.5t49 120.5q0 41 -17 76t-44 63.5t-56.5 55.5t-56.5 53l-178 180q-53 49 -123 50q-43 0 -72.5 -17.5t-46.5 -17.5q-12 0 -38.5 21.5t-55 49t-50 56t-21.5 41.5z" />
...
```

Would it be effective to take my svg icon code, paste it in as a new glyph element and assign an unused unicode char?

Comment: did you found a solution? or you just chose another plugging?

Comment: link for '.svg version of Font Awesome' not found. Please update.

Comment: Here's the relevant documentation: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Customize-Font-Awesome

Comment: Link is broken. Use https://fontawesome.com/v6.0/icons

Answer (score 135):

Give [Icomoon](http://icomoon.io/app/) a try. You can upload your own SVGs, add them to the library, then create a custom font combining FontAwesome with your own icons.

Comment: Hi, I have generated font icons with a folder containing svg icons. But later i want to add a single icon to that , Is it possible to add ? or again i have to generate with the folder?.

Answer (score 40):

In Font Awesome 5, you can create custom icons with your own SVG data. Here's a [demo GitHub repo](https://github.com/mlwilkerson/fa-custom-icon-demo) that you can play with. And [here's a CodePen](https://codepen.io/fontawesome/pen/YaaYqP) that shows how something similar might be done in `<script>` blocks.

In either case, it simply involves using `library.add()` to add an object like this:

```
export const faSomeObjectName = {
  // Use a prefix like 'fac' that doesn't conflict with a prefix in the standard Font Awesome styles
  // (So avoid fab, fal, fas, far, fa)
  prefix: string,
  iconName: string, // Any name you like
  icon: [
    number, // width
    number, // height
    string[], // ligatures
    string, // unicode (if relevant)
    string // svg path data
  ]
}
```

Note that the element labelled by the comment "svg path data" in the code sample is what will be assigned as the value of the `d` attribute on a `<path>` element that is a child of the `<svg>`. Like this (leaving out some details for clarity):

```
<svg>
  <path d=SVG_PATH_DATA></path>
</svg>
```

(Adapted from my similar answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50338775/4642871)

Comment: What if we want to use the standard prefixes, so the new svg can fit into the website?

Comment: You can use whatever prefix you like. But if you use a standard prefix (`fab`, `fas`, `far`, `fal`) you'll be at greater risk of a naming conflict—if not now, then possibly in the future as we continue adding icons with those standard prefixes. Using a custom prefix won't make an svg any less likely to "fit into the website"—but I'm not sure what you mean by that phrase, so perhaps you could clarify?

Comment: We need a specific social brand icon (with 200M+ users), which was requested already.
We would like to add this svg icon to the pro version to use it on a website, without making html/css exceptions / else cases.
All the other brands have icons already, so the fab class is present on the elements (and the actually selected brand is added dinamycally to the css)

Comment: Yes that will work fine to use the standard prefix to add your custom icon. Just bear in mind that if the icon name ends up being the same as something we add to that prefix later, there will be a conflict. So maybe choose an icon name that is unlikely to conflict? Forked CodePen to demonstrate: https://codepen.io/fontawesome/pen/pZWXYX

Comment: My SVG came from an adobe AI file, and had multiple paths. This prevented me from being able to properly set the "d" parameter specified above. I had to first convert the AI file into a compound path before exporting it as an SVG. I learned how to do that here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/35054/making-multiple-vectors-one-single-vector-in-illustrator

Comment: You can use multiple paths as the "svg path data" can be a string or string[]

Answer (score 29):

I suggest keeping your icons separate from **FontAwesome** and create and maintain your own custom library. Personally, I think it is much easier to maintain keeping **FontAwesome** separate if you are going to be creating your own icon library. You can then have FontAwesome loaded into your site from a CDN and never have to worry about keeping it up-to-date.

When creating your own custom icons, create each icon via **Adobe Illustrator** or similar software. Once your icons are created, save each individually in `SVG` format on your computer.

Next, head on over to **IcoMoon**: http://icomoon.io , which has the best font generating software (in my opinion), and it's free. **IcoMoon** will allow you to import your individual svg-saved fonts into a font library, then generate your custom icon glyph library in `eot`, `ttf`, `woff`, and `svg`. One format **IcoMoon** does not generate is `woff2`.

After generating your icon pack at **IcoMoon**, head over to **FontSquirrel**: http://fontsquirrel.com and use their font generator. Use your `ttf` file generated at **IcoMoon**. In the newly generated icon pack created, you'll now have your icon pack in `woff2` format.

Make sure the files for `eot`, `ttf`, `svg`, `woff`, and `woff2` are all the same name. You are generating an icon pack from two different websites/software, and they do name their generated output differently.

You'll have CSS generated for your icon pack at both locations. But the CSS generated at **IcoMoon** will not include the `woff2` format in your `@font-face {}` declaration. Make sure to add that when you're adding your CSS to your project:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'customiconpackname';
    src: url('../fonts/customiconpack.eot?lchn8y');
    src: url('../fonts/customiconpack.eot?lchn8y#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/customiconpack.ttf?lchn8y') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/customiconpack.woff2?lchn8y') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/customiconpack.woff?lchn8y') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/customiconpack.svg?lchn8y#customiconpack') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Keep in mind that you can get the glyph unicode values of each icon in your icon pack using the **IcoMoon** software. These values can be helpful in assigning your icons via CSS, as in (assuming we're using the `font-family` declared in the example `@font-face {...}` above):

```
selector:after {
    font-family: 'customiconpackname';
    content: '\e953';
    }
```

You can also get the glyph unicode value `e953` if you open the font-pack-generated `svg` file in a text editor. E.g.:

```
<glyph unicode="&#xe953;" glyph-name="eye" ... />
```

Comment: not working ,.,. complete the whole process just icon not appear instead numbers appear

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more? I'm happy to help you with your problem. Did you specify `font-family: customiconpack;` with your `selector:after` ? Let me update my solution right now for the `selector:after` code example.

Comment: i uploaded the my icon svg file ,.  i downlaoded the file,., i put those in the project add new css file into the project copied your code into the file changed the code with my icon code ,. didn't work ,.

Comment: Please join this chat room I created so we can discuss the problem easier: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132402/fontawesome-icomoon-and-css-problems

Comment: bro i was unable to join the chat room ,. please help me jow to

Comment: I'm commenting here just to let others know that the issue was that you created your SVG in Illustrator from an imported PNG. You must recreate your icon as a vector. PNG is a raster format and has no vector curves.

Answer (score 19):

Depends on what you have. If your svg icon is just a path, then it's easy enough to add that glyph by just copying the 'd' attribute to a new <glyph> element. However, the path needs to be scaled to the font's coordinate system (the EM-square, which typically is [0,0,2048,2048] - the standard for Truetype fonts) and aligned with the baseline you want.

Not all browsers support svg fonts however, so you're going to have to convert it to other formats too if you want it to work everywhere.

[Fontforge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/) can import svg files (select a glyph slot, File > Import and then select your svg image), and you can then convert to all the relevant font formats (svg, truetype, woff etc).

Answer (score 14):

Similar approach to @Samuel-bergström:

- Download Fontawesome SVG https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/src/assets/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg
- Download FontForge http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/downloads/
- Download Inkscape
- Open Inskscape and create a single layer shape as your new font icon
- Save SVG file, Close Inkscape
- Open FontForge (If you have multiple monitors, use Windows-LeftArrow, to reposition as they have strange SWING java windows that go off monitor, and have modal problems with popups - I had to check my task bar for some)
- File | Open fontawesome-webfont.svg
- File | Import
- Scroll to the bottom, Right Click on Icon | Glyph Info
- Update Glyph Name to uniFXXX (XXX is something like 501, a higher number than the highest Unicode used in v4.5 of FontAwesome)
- Unicode Vlaue U+fXXX
- Click OK
- File | Save
- File | Generate Fonts ...
- Close FontForge
- Open your web project
- Copy your font files to the (in my project) "\Content\fonts\" folder.
- Edit "\Content\styles\fa\path.less" to be like:

```css
@font-face {
      font-family: 'FontAwesome';
      //src: url('@{fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=@{fa-version}');
      src: 
     //url('@{fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=@{fa-version}') format('embedded-opentype'),
        //url('@{fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=@{fa-version}') format('woff2'),
        url('@{fa-font-path}/fontawesomeregular.woff?v=@{fa-version}') format('woff'),
        url('@{fa-font-path}/fontawesomeregular.ttf?v=@{fa-version}') format('truetype'),
        url('@{fa-font-path}/fontawesomeregular.svg?v=@{fa-version}#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
    //  src: url('@{fa-font-path}/FontAwesome.otf') format('opentype'); // used when developing fonts
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
    }
```

I know it may be 'controversial' to comment out other file types, but happy to hear how to generate .eot or .otf files in the comments.

- and finally, as Samuel mentions, update your CSS/LESS with:

  .fa-XXX:before { content: "\f501"; }

Answer (score 3):

I researched a bit into SVG webfonts and font creation, in my eyes if you want to "add" fonts to font-awesome already existing font you need to do the following:

go to inkscape and create a glyph, save it as SVG so you could read the code, make sure to assign it a unicode character which is not currently used so it will not conflict with any of the existing glyphs in the font. this could be hard so i think a better simpler approad would be replacing an existing glyph with your own (just choose one you dont use, copy the first part:

Save the svg then convert it to web-font using any online converter so your webfont would work in all browsers.

once this is done, you should have either an SVG with one of the glyphs replaced in which case youre done. if not you need to create the CSS for your new glyph, in this case try and reuse FAs existing CSS, and  only add

```
>##CSS##
>.FA.NEW-GLYPH:after {
>content:'WHATEVER AVAILABLE UNICODE CHARACTER YOU FOUND'
>(other conditions should be copied from other fonts)
>}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want some icons (or all) from font-awesome including yout custom svg icons you can:

1- Go to http://fontawesome.io/ Download the zip and extract-it for example in your Desktop.

2- Go to http://fontastic.me/ use your email to create an account.

3- Once you have been logged-in click on the header option: Add More Icons.

4- Select the SVG of font-awesome located in your extracted zip inside fonts.

5- Repeat the procces uploading your own svg files.

6- Inside Home (at the header of the page) Select the icons you want to download, customize them to give your custom names and select publish to have a link or download the fonts and css.

Sorry about my english ! :D

Comment: That will works but I think it is better to create your own custom icon library and using fontawesome side. It will permit to get fontawesome updated (with new icons).