# Making own Icon and adding hyperlink

Tags: html, css

I want to open a hyperlink by clicking on Icon, but I want to use my own image (jpg/png/svg) as Icon.

This is demo code. Do I have to make svg file and upload on below given website and use these Icons.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <i class="fa fa-cloud"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-car"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-file"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, can you show an example of where your own icon will be in code and also details regarding what it is that you wish to open?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426172/add-custom-icons-to-font-awesome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This allows to clickable icon

```
<a href="your link here"> <i class="fa fa-dribbble fa-4x"></i></a>
<a href="your link here"> <i class="fa fa-behance-square fa-4x"></i></a>
<a href="your link here"> <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-4x"></i></a>
<a href="your link here"> <i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-4x"></i></a>
<a href="your link here"> <i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-4x"></i></a>
```

This allows your custom image (png preffred) as your icon

```
<a href"clickable link here"><img src="icon.png"></a>
```

Comment: I don't think the OP is wanting to add a favicon, but rather add custom icons to FontAwesome

Comment: I'm assuming he wants to add it to Font Awesome since both the FA style sheet and classes are both in his code. He also mentions using the icon as a link, which would also rule out a favicon.

Comment: Downvoting does not unnecessarily create a negative imapct, and besides, I did not downvote you.