# How do i add an octicon to font awesome?

Tags: css, font-awesome, webfonts, octicons

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this but I'll ask it anyway. Warn me if this is the wrong place and i'll delete this question.

My question is how do I add an octicon to font awesome. I already have the octicon made i just don't know how i'd go about adding it to "Font Awesome".

I haven't found much information on this online.

Comment: Whith "octicon" do you mean add a customized icon to Font Awesome?

Comment: Yes. Thats what i mean

Comment: Not sure if you can add icons to fontawesome but you could use fontello.com to upload your custom icons and select (among others) icons from fontawesome to create a custom set of icons.

Comment: Its open source so i assume anyone could fork it and add icons

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add custom icons to font awesome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426172/add-custom-icons-to-font-awesome)

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to add it to their library the only way is to request them to add it

Comment: Only they can add it?