# How are Button Fonts Created?

Tags: button, fonts

I notice that some buttons have faces that are generated by a special font. For example, the  TinyMCE editor has the button below for unlink:

[image]

The markup for the button is:[image]

You can see they have a special tinymce font to generate these button faces.

But if I try to create my own background images for the buttons they look terrible! Even though all the lines I used in FireWorks are 1px, they look fat, splotchy, and don't all have the same width:

[image]

How can I create fine line button faces like the ones generated by fonts?

Thanks

Comment: The relatively obvious answer would be "you make a font, and use that". And to preempt "how do I make a font", there are a lot of tools and website at your disposal for that, Google will definitely be your friend here.

Comment: I found the solution in a SO article at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426172/add-custom-icons-to-font-awesome   The solution was to not make a font at all, but to use Inkscape to generate vector SVG images, which I could then apply to the button face.

Comment: sure, as long as you're okay with the smoothing that SVG scaling can incur (fonts with hinting do bitmap rasterization due to scaling signficantly better than just plain SVG files)