# Font awesome stacking square and square-o don't align

Tags: html, icons, font-awesome

I'm trying to make this using font-awesome stacking

[image]

I've tried two ways, but both are ugly. The problem is that `fa-square` and `fa-square-o` are different sizes, so when you stack them, they don't line up!

[my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jdhenckel/e1Lgo85h/3/)

```
<span class="fa fa-stack">
  <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-1x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-plus-square fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>

<span class="fa fa-stack">
  <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
```

The result is

[image]

I have tried to scale down the `fa-square` by 86% using css.  However, that is very fragile, because it depends on the browser and the zoom setting. I would like the solution to look good on both Chrome and IE11 at multiple zoom levels.

Comment: That's reported in [GitHub issue 5156](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/5156), and I see no good workaround

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might help.

```css
body {
  background-color: tan;
  font-size: 100px;
}

.fix:before {
 background: #000;
 border-radius: 20%;
 padding: 1% 5%;
}

.fix-2:before {
 background: #000;
 border-radius: 20%;
 padding: 1% 10%;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span class="fa fa-stack">
  <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-1x fix"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-plus-square fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>

<!-- Without Stacking -->
<i class="fa fa-plus-square fa-inverse fix-2"></i>
```

Comment: That's brilliant!! It seems to work on both IE and Chrome.  THANKS!!

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, if you want to use the icons of Font-Awesome, you will have to contribute to the project by making a **new generation of fa-square** and all the derivatives (rss-square, ...) to standardize the size of the icons.

Developers no longer accept pull-request for icons so it may take a long time before it is accepted. (As Hugues M. said, it's a known [bug](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/5156))

The workarounds I see:

- Create your own icon based on a font (see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426172/add-custom-icons-to-font-awesome)), override the square unicode (f0c8) or get an other free one. (and push your solution in github). It is generic, you can dynamically change the color but it take a long time.
- Or simply make an image ([SVG](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/) or something else) for your project, it's quick but less malleable.