# How to add new SVG icon to font awesome

Tags: css, svg, font-awesome

I am trying to use font awesome for many aspects of web project, so there comes 
a problem about how to add new SVG icons to font awesome css files. 
My develop environment is ASP with Visual Studio 2012, and operation system is 
windows 10. Is there any clear instructions or manual for adding SVG icon which
drawing by myself to font awesome? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You may find this answer useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426172/add-custom-icons-to-font-awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to create your own icons??

You can use this website https://icomoon.io/app to create essentially your own icon pack, it will generate everything for you and then you just need to use the classnames they created, exactly how you would use font-awesome.

Comment: Could I combind it into font awesome , or a new css for that, thanks.

Comment: Its not wise to add things to font awesome, like I said this website will do everything for you generate the icons and create the css you need then all you need to do is `<i class="icon-your-new-icon"></i>`

Comment: could I use the icon off-line and put the related data into my project? thanks.

Comment: Im  not sure what you mean

Comment: like font awesome, I include its css files into my asp project, and then, when I need, I include the css file on <head></head>, using <i class="fas fa-camera-retro"></i> to represent the icon on web control, like button, thanks.

Comment: You do the exact same thing with the css file the is generated for you from icomoon