# Can Custom Icons Be Added to font-awesome-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, font-awesome, react-font-awesome

This [issue](https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome/issues/165) on the [react-font-awesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome) repo suggests that this is at least possible, but doesn't outline what would be needed to add a custom SVG icon.

React Font Awesome allows you to add icons from libraries, however only from their own libraries.

**Is there any way to create a library of your own icons and add that?**

Why do I want to do this? Because react-font-awesome has build a lot of useful functionality around its `<FontAwesomeIcon />` component and I would like to be able to use this single component for all the icons in my app, regardless of whether they are Font Awesome icons or my own.

Note: I understand how to author SVG files, I'm interested in packaging them as a library that can be loaded into react-font-awesome.

Comment: why do you want to load them into react-font-awsome? If you package them as a library cant you just use them as your own library, independent of react-font-awesome?

Comment: @vhflat Just for a consistent API. I don't want to care whether I'm asking for a Font Awesome icon or a custom icon. React Font Awesome already offers a simple abstraction that allows me to use a react component that adds a lot of useful functionality:
`<FontAwesomeIcon icon="igloo" />`. I don't want to have to duplicate this functionality and API for my own icons.

Comment: Probably more one for https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It is possible. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50339724/2190075

Answer (score 5):

I just came across this issue today and solved it by creating an icon definition without having to do `library.add()`.

### Example

[image: Edit fontawesome-react custom icon example]

#### Icons

For this example, I'm using two icons:

1. A [native Font Awesome icon](https://fontawesome.com/icons/font-awesome?s=solid)

   [image: font awesome icon]
2. A [custom Outlook icon from Simple Icons](https://simpleicons.org/?q=outlook)

   [image: outlook icon]

#### Steps

1. Create a file that contains the custom icon definition.

   **simpleIconsMicrosoftOutlook.ts**

   ```
   import {
     IconDefinition,
     IconName,
     IconPrefix
   } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";

   export const simpleIconsMicrosoftOutlook: IconDefinition = {
     icon: [
       // SVG viewbox width (in pixels)
       24,

       // SVG viewbox height (in pixels)
       24,

       // Aliases (not needed)
       [],

       // Unicode as hex value (not needed)
       "",

       // SVG path data
       "M7.88 12.04q0 .45-.11.87-.1.41-.33.74-.22.33-.58.52-.37.2-.87.2t-.85-.2q-.35-.21-.57-.55-.22-.33-.33-.75-.1-.42-.1-.86t.1-.87q.1-.43.34-.76.22-.34.59-.54.36-.2.87-.2t.86.2q.35.21.57.55.22.34.31.77.1.43.1.88zM24 12v9.38q0 .46-.33.8-.33.32-.8.32H7.13q-.46 0-.8-.33-.32-.33-.32-.8V18H1q-.41 0-.7-.3-.3-.29-.3-.7V7q0-.41.3-.7Q.58 6 1 6h6.5V2.55q0-.44.3-.75.3-.3.75-.3h12.9q.44 0 .75.3.3.3.3.75V10.85l1.24.72h.01q.1.07.18.18.07.12.07.25zm-6-8.25v3h3v-3zm0 4.5v3h3v-3zm0 4.5v1.83l3.05-1.83zm-5.25-9v3h3.75v-3zm0 4.5v3h3.75v-3zm0 4.5v2.03l2.41 1.5 1.34-.8v-2.73zM9 3.75V6h2l.13.01.12.04v-2.3zM5.98 15.98q.9 0 1.6-.3.7-.32 1.19-.86.48-.55.73-1.28.25-.74.25-1.61 0-.83-.25-1.55-.24-.71-.71-1.24t-1.15-.83q-.68-.3-1.55-.3-.92 0-1.64.3-.71.3-1.2.85-.5.54-.75 1.3-.25.74-.25 1.63 0 .85.26 1.56.26.72.74 1.23.48.52 1.17.81.69.3 1.56.3zM7.5 21h12.39L12 16.08V17q0 .41-.3.7-.29.3-.7.3H7.5zm15-.13v-7.24l-5.9 3.54Z"
     ],
     iconName: "simple-icons-microsoft-outlook" as IconName,
     prefix: "simple-icons" as IconPrefix
   };
   ```
2. Pass the custom icon as a prop to `FontAwesomeIcon`:

   **App.tsx**

   ```
   import { faFontAwesome } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
   import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

   import { simpleIconsMicrosoftOutlook } from "./simpleIconsMicrosoftOutlook";

   import "./styles.css";

   const App = () => {
     return (
       <>
         <p>
           <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFontAwesome} />
           Native icon from <b>Font Awesome</b>
         </p>

         <p>
           <FontAwesomeIcon icon={simpleIconsMicrosoftOutlook} />
           Custom icon from <b>Simple Icons</b>
         </p>
       </>
     );
   };

   export default App;
   ```
3. Also, the css for reference:

   **styles.css**

   ```css
   body {
     font-family: sans-serif;
     font-size: 1.5rem;
   }

   svg {
     margin-right: 0.5rem;
   }

   svg.fa-font-awesome[data-prefix="fas"] {
     color: crimson;
   }

   svg.fa-simple-icons-microsoft-outlook[data-prefix="simple-icons"] {
     /*
     * Outlook cyan.
     * See brand color at https://simpleicons.org/?q=outlook
     */
     color: #0078d4;
   }
   ```
4. Result:

   [image: example preview]

Answer (score 2):

According to the README you can add other icon packages by using `library.add()`

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'
import { faCheckSquare, faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

library.add(fab, faCheckSquare, faCoffee)
```

So if you format your own icon package in the same way as in for example [free-brands-svg-icons](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/master/js-packages/%40fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons), your should be able to add it.

Comment: This is not the most convenient format to define your icons in, but I'm quite sure if you have consistent SVG files it is possible to cook something up. Thanks for the suggestion, still considering if it's worth it in my case.