# Using IcoMoon app for custom Awesome font

Tags: svg, fonts, metadata, font-awesome, icomoon

This is my first attempt to try and create a custom "awesome fonts". And more specifically I want to use the current awesome font and expand its content with a few new custom svg icons that I have created.

[Add custom icons to font awesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426172/add-custom-icons-to-font-awesome)

While searching I came across the topic above in which the IcoMoon app was suggested. Even though I have created my custom svg files. I can't get to understand how to use the IconMoon app as from what I see it only creates libraries but not the code needed for the awesome font to function with the additional custom icons.

The awesome font has the following as metadata:

```
categories.yml
icons.json
icons.yml
shims.json
shims.yml
sponsors.yml
```

Does anyone knows what's the process that has to be used with using IcoMoon app in order to create a functional custom "awesome font"? I'm looking forward for any insightful information you might have!

Comment: Or use a modern Web Component: https://iconmeister.github.io

Comment: I work with icomoon, it's quite simple. If you have your SVG icons in separated files, you create a font in Icomooon and add those icons one by one, then export them and get a ready icon font just like the Font Awesome