How to import custom SVG icon on font awesome 4.7?
Ahoy devs,
I need your help.
I run a website since 8 years which use Font Awesome 4.7 and there is now new icons (Tiktok, new Twitter X logo, ...) and I want to update my website with some SVG icons which are not in FA 4.7,
I can't (and don't want) update font awesome as it will change all my icons size and design (I tried and I need to keep the 4.7 version), and my database store icons thought FA class.
Example:
id    articleName        articleIcon    articleContent
1    First article         fa-home        Hello world !
2    Second Article       fa-facebook      Hello !

So I need to create some class to work with Font Awesome and be able to use an SVG with the class "fa-tiktok", but I don't have idea to do this, and I don't find any tutorial.
If you know a hack or simple css line to do this, I would be happy to update my website and add custom icons in svg,
Thanks in advance

why not considering a separate icon library like heroicons or fluenticons. Moreover, look at this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426172/add-custom-icons-to-font-awesome?rq=2

Please revise your question to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please clarify, if your legacy application usage deploys fontAwesome in icon-font mode or as script injected svgs. Pardon me, but your pseudo code example is not very helpful
